Force-free condition from Cauchy stress
I have an outer Stokes problem, i.e. I want to solve (outisde of the ball $\{ r \leq l\}$):
$$ \begin{cases} \Delta u - \nabla p=0\\
\nabla \cdot u=0\\
B.C. \text{ on } u \text{ in } \{r=l\}\\
u(x) \to - U \mathbf{e_z} \text{ as } |x| \to + \infty
\end{cases}$$
whose boundary conditions are assigned on a sphere of radius $r=l$. These boundary conditions are in principle free, but I'll explain later what condition I need them to satisfy. These equations describe the velocity field generated by a spherical object moving at velocity $U \mathbf{e_z}$ in the frame of the object. Now, given the boundary conditions I am interested in, I can find both the velocity $u$ and the pressure $p$. Such conditions are axisymmetric, and I want to check that, under some assumptions on the boundary conditions, the total force on the fluid is zero, but I am not sure how to do it. I tried to calculate the force on each point of $\{r=l\}$ using the stress tensor, and then I want to impose that the net force on the fluid is zero. So, I want my boundary conditions to be so that the total force (maybe the toatl work would be the correct requirement?) the body exerts on the fluid is 0.
The boundary conditions are not the matter though. The point is: given the stress tensor $T$ on $\{ r=l\}$, what is the correct way to impose the aforementioned force free condition?

What are your expressions for the components of the stress tensor in spherical coordinates for this stokes solution?

The expressions don't matter that much, my question would be more on a generale level. The thing is: given the stress tensor on a surface, how do I calculate the total work (if this is the correct concept to use here, I am not 100% sure) that the surface does on the fluid? After I can do this, I can tune the boundary conditions so that the resulting velocity and pressure give me a 0 work on the fluid, but I can do that by myself. The problem is to find the work on the fluid given the stress tensor.

In the rest frame of the sphere, the surface is not moving, so the work done by the sphere surface on the fluid is zero.

In the rest frame of the far-field fluid, the work the sphere does on the fluid is the drag force time the sphere velocity.

Disclaimer
This answer will likely go beyond your current proficiency with math tools, but nobody says that all the problems (and this looks like quite a challenging one - inverse problem on a PDE) have easy solutions.
Doubts, and things that are not clear in your question
I'll list here some not-so-clear points in your question, to may help in trying to give you an answer.

is this an inner- or outer-flow problem? Is the fluid inside or outside the sphere? If it's outside the sphere, you need to a far-field (finite or infinite) surface to delimit the domain of interest, and prescribe boundary conditions there;

are the boundary conditions determined (e.g. by physics) or can they be considered as "free" field that can be tuned to fit the required condition of net zero force?

usually one solves the direct problem: boundary conditions are prescribed, the differential problem is solved, and the force is a consequence of the physics governed by the mathematical problem
sometimes we're interested in a inverse problem, e.g. if boundary conditions are "free" fields that can be tuned to satisfy "extra" conditions like the one about the force.



Solution: constrained optimization approach
I'll show you an example, assuming that the boundary is the union of two regions $\partial \Omega = S_D \cup S_N$, being Dirichlet boundary conditions prescribed on  $S_D$ and Neumann boundary conditions on  $S_N$
$$\begin{cases}
- \Delta \mathbf{u} + \nabla P = 0 \hspace{40pt} \mathbf{r} \in \Omega \\
\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u} = 0 \\
\mathbf{u} = \mathbf{b} \hspace{83pt} \mathbf{r} \in S_D \\
-\mathbf{\hat{n}} \cdot \nabla \mathbf{u} + P \mathbf{\hat{n}} = \mathbf{g} \hspace{28pt} \mathbf{r} \in S_N \\
\end{cases}$$
I'd write it as a constrained optimization problem, considering:

the free field $\mathbf{b}(\mathbf{r})$, $\mathbf{r} \in S_D$, as the independent variable
a norm $|| \mathbf{b} ||^2_{2,S_D} =\int_{S_D} \mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{b}$ of the free field as the optimization variable, to avoid infinite solutions and get a well-defined problem
differential equations, boundary conditions and the condition on the force $\mathbf{F} = \int_{S_D} -\mathbf{\hat{n}} \cdot \nabla \mathbf{u} + P \mathbf{\hat{n}} = \mathbf{0}$  (assuming this expression for the "force")

by means of the Lagrange multiplier method, namely defining the constrained cost function
$$\begin{aligned}
J & = \frac{1}{2} \int_{S_D} \mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{b} + \\
  & - \int_{\Omega} \mathbf{w} \cdot \left( - \Delta \mathbf{u} + \nabla P\right)
- \int_{\Omega} Q \nabla \cdot \mathbf{u} + \\
& - \int_{S_D} \mathbf{v} \cdot \left( \mathbf{u} - \mathbf{b} \right)
- \int_{S_N} \mathbf{h} \cdot \left( -\mathbf{\hat{n}} \cdot \nabla \mathbf{u} + P \mathbf{\hat{n}} - \mathbf{g}\right) + \\
& - \lambda  \int_{S_D} -\mathbf{\hat{n}} \cdot \nabla \mathbf{u} + P \mathbf{\hat{n}}
\end{aligned}$$
and performing optimization on that.

Edited the question, I hope it's clearer!
